# Display long bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

I need to load a very long (approx 15K px) black-and-white bitmap which would have screen width.

I tried several approaches and the best seems using `Glide`:

```
private fun loadGlideScreenWideCompress(context: Context, imageView: AppCompatImageView) {
    imageView.adjustViewBounds = true
    val params = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    imageView.layoutParams = params

    GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(imageRes)
            .encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView)
}
```

The problem is - image quality is lost. The image is blurred and text is not readable.

I tried to use `BitmapRegionDecoder`. I did not see the quality loss or memory issues. However, it decodes just a portion of the image. I do not really understand how to use it: to decode next part on scroll event? This would be hard to implement. Measure the drawable height and passing full height to the `BitmapRegionDecoder` intuitively feels wrong because this is the decoder is just for regions.

Another issue is that the image is large and I need it to work for all screen sizes. If I take the largest possible size and then scale it, I would need to perform expensive bitmap creating operations and block the main thread potentially.

The conventional approach does not work and give OOM exceptions:

```
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.Options().run {
        inJustDecodeBounds = true
        inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8
        inDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, imageRes, this)
    }
    imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Code with scaling down:

```
val res = context.resources
    val display = res.displayMetrics
    val dr = res.getDrawable(imageRes!!)
    val original = (dr as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

    val scale = original.width / display.widthPixels
    val scaledBitmap = BitmapDrawable(res, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            original,
            display.widthPixels,
            original.height / scale,
            true
    ))
    imageView.adjustViewBounds = true

    val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    scaledBitmap.bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, bos)
    val decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(
            ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()),
            false
    )

    val rect = Rect(
            0,
            0,
            scaledBitmap.intrinsicWidth,
            scaledBitmap.intrinsicHeight
    )
    val bitmapFactoryOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
    bitmapFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
    bitmapFactoryOptions.inDensity = display.densityDpi;
    val bmp = decoder.decodeRegion(rect, bitmapFactoryOptions);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)
```

So the question is: What would be the best approach in this situation and how to use `BitmapRegionDecoder` correctly?

Comment: "This would be hard to implement" -- use a library that did it for you, such as [this one](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks I will try this library

Comment: @CommonsWare I used the library - it works very well on many devices, but not all of them. I have a problem on Nexus 5 / Android 5.0, where decoding last part of the bitmap does not work. Error message is this: `E/SubsamplingScaleImageView: Failed to decode tile
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Skia image decoder returned null bitmap - image format may not be supported
        at com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.decoder.SkiaImageRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(SkiaImageRegionDecoder.java:123)`

Comment: Consider publishing a sample project and filing a bug report with the library author. Or, look at other libraries offering pinch-to-zoom images, such as [this one](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). Or, just look at how they use `BitmapRegionDecoder` and create something yourself.

Comment: It helped to remove the alpha channel from the PNG